# Unable to create work profile in Some devices

Tags: android, device, profile, user-profile, android-package-managers

I found that we can't create work profile in some devices because they don't have android.software.managed_users features in devices whereas i can create device owner in that device even though device version is marshmallow. I can check that by code

```
System.out.println(" can create work profile=" + pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MANAGED_USERS));
```

or by adb command

```
adb shell pm list features
```

so anyone know what can i do so that i can create work profile in any device.
or any alternate idea to get this feature android.software.managed_users in device.

Comment: What device is it? make and model? Have you tested on any other devices?

Comment: The devices on which i tested are Motorola G3 and samsung tab. As i explain in my question that if device not have Managed_user feature it will not create work profile. So if you are testing you can test in any device by finding it have feature or not.